# Categorize/Group data from table using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have stored the physical locations of specific files in my database with download counters to provide downloads via shorter urls like `/Download/a4s`. Each file has a `categoryId` assigned via foreign keys which just describes to which course/lecture it belongs for an easier overview. The table `fileCategories` basically looks like this

```
categoryId | categoryName
---------------------------
         1 | Lecture 1
         2 | Lecture 2
         3 | Personal Stuff
```

Assume that I have a `files` table which looks like this with some other columns I did omit

```
fileId | categoryId | filePath     | ...
----------------------------------------
     1 |          1 | /Foo/Bar.pdf | ...
     2 |          1 | /Foo/Baz.pdf | ...
     3 |          2 | /Bar/Foo.pdf | ...
     4 |          2 | /Baz/Foo.pdf | ...
     5 |          3 | /Bar/Baz.pdf | ...
```

I have created a page which should display some data about those files and group them by their categories which produces a very simple html table which looks like this:

```
Id | Path         | ...
-----------------------
Lecture 1
-----------------------
 1 | /Foo/Bar.pdf | ...
 2 | /Foo/Baz.pdf | ...
-----------------------
Lecture 2
-----------------------
 3 | /Bar/Foo.pdf | ...
 4 | /Baz/Foo.pdf | ...
-----------------------
Personal Stuff
-----------------------
 5 | /Bar/Baz.pdf | ...
```

So far I am using multiple SQL queries to fetch and store all categories in PHP arrays and append file entries to those arrays when iterating over the `files` table. It is highly unlikely this is the best method even though the number of files is pretty small. I was wondering whether there is a query which will automatically sort those entries into temporary tables (just a spontaneous guess to use those) which I can output to drastically improve my current way to obtain the data.

Comment: You should learn about `JOIN`.  Then, you'll have to do some additional processing in php to get the output you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually I know about joining tables yet I was curious to what extent one could move the processing from PHP to SQL in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do this with just mysql but a combination of `JOIN` and some PHP.

```
SELECT * FROM files f LEFT JOIN fileCategories c USING (categoryId) ORDER BY c.categoryName ASC
```

Be sure to order by the category first (name or ID) and optionally order by other params after that to allow the following code example to work as expected.

in PHP then iterate over the result, remember the category id from each row and if it changes you can output the category delimiter. assumung the query result is stored in `$dbRes`

Example Code:

```
$lastCategoryId = null;
while ($row = $dbRes->fetchRow()) {
    if ($lastCategoryId !== $row['categoryId']) {
        echo "--------------------" . PHP_EOL;
        echo $row['categoryName'] . PHP_EOL
        echo "--------------------" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo $row['filePath'] . PHP_EOL;
    $lastCategoryId = $row['categoryId'];
}
```

Comment: Your query seems to be invalid - instead of `USING categoryId` it should be `ON c.categoryId = f.categoryId` I guess?

Comment: if the fieldnames are the same in both tables to join, `USING fieldname` is an equivalent to `ON table1.fieldname = table2.fieldname`